# Unknown class in interface builder file yet class exists

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

This question has been asked before but I can't see any cause relevant to my issue.

I've created a very simple view controller and trying to load it but getting an unknown class MapViewController in interface builder file error. Here are some relevant parts:

```
class MapViewController: UIViewController {
    ...
}

...
let storyboard : UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
let  mapViewController = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("MapViewControllerID") as MapViewController
```

[image]

- The MapViewController.swift file is included in the Compile Sources.
- The storyboard has the default name of Main.storyboard
- Have exited Xcode, rebuilt, deleted the app on the device.

The problem still persists, any suggestions?

(Using Xcode beta 4)

Comment: This would be way easier for us to diagnose and fix if you created an example project on Github that we could run and test ourselves.

Comment: Double check the module name (I know it's supposed to be picked up automatically but recently another person had similar issues)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

How I solved this was to 
1) Delete the derived data
2) Rename the class to MyMapViewController
3) Delete derived data again
4) Rename the class back to MapViewController

Answer (score 0):

My problem was I had accidentally selected a module under the class entry for custom class in IB. Once I deselected that everything worked.